# Using CKEditor in GWT UIBinder dialog box

Tags: javascript, gwt, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor in GWT dialog box within a UI binder.  I have done following

Included in module html file

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Included in UI binder XML file

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" rows="5" cols="15"></textarea>
```

Included UI Binder JAVA file

```
public static native void loadckeditor() 
/*-{

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
}-*/;
```

The error I get is "CKEDITOR is not defined"
I am no expert in JS but CKEDITOR fulfills my whole functionality and is to be used as per customer specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ScriptInjector:
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html

```
 ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://example.com/foo.js").setCallback(
 new Callback() {
    public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
      Window.alert("Script load failed.");
    }
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
       // insert code to setup the CKEditor
    }
 }).inject();
```

I think the javascript is not in the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend CKEDITOR variable with $wnd:

```
$wnd.CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

From the [docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

> When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI,
>   you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled
>   script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically
>   initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.